# Can this be optimized even further using object methods or other way in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am trying to remove a user from an array in react javascript the text is given to the function that needs to be deleted and runs through the function below, `this.state.users` contain objects with properties like:

> 0: {user_id: "001"  , first_name: "john", last_name: "doe", email: 
>   "john@doe.com"}
>
> 1: {user_id: "002"  , first_name: "mike", last_name: "ty", email: 
>   "mike@ty.com"}

I'm wondering if this can be optimized even further for large sets of data? or is it already optimized thanks!

```
removeUser(text){
  var updatedUsers = this.state.users;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i< updatedUsers.length;i++)
  {
    if(updatedUsers[i].user_id == text)
      break;
    }
    updatedUsers.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({users: updatedUsers});
  }
}
```

Comment: Side-note, you are mutating the state directly. You need to create a copy of your `users` array. For example: `var updatedUsers = this.state.users.slice();`

Comment: General advice beyond this Q: Removing elements of an array inside a loop iterating over the array's elements is bad. Never add or remove elements from a collection you are iterating over.

Comment: is it a bad practice can you enlighten me more @Chris

Comment: it might cause bugs ? @morre ? thanks all

Comment: Even when it works, it is a hard almost philosophical problem: Think about it, if you remove an item, how does that affect the iteration? What does it do to the stop condition? The next element? Iteration over a collection is not well defined for a length-changing collection, the results are ambiguous and depend on too many things that are not obvious. So even when it happens to work, having to read such a construct should ring all alarm bells and raise your hair (if there is any). How do you cut someone's hair who keeps wiggling around in the chair? You don't want a moving target.

Comment: I see, got it thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use array's `filter`:

```
removeUser (text) {
  this.setState({
    users: this.state.users.filter((u) => u.user_id !== text)
  })
}
```

Comment: awesome :) is there a way instead of using filter method I want to target that array data that matches the user_id ?

Comment: @Tommy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: thank you very much @lilezek, i am already getting the data that I want to edit, but how can I alter it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of [redux's](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.md#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays) approach.

```
removeUser(text) {
  const { users } = this.state
  const index = users.findIndex(user => user.user_id === text)

  this.setState({
    users: [
      ...users.slice(0, index), // every user before index
      ...users.slice(index + 1), // every user after index
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: i'm still learning react and haven't tried redux, not to offend but im curious how can I test if this is the better solution than @lilezek thank you

Comment: It's not a better solution. Both suggestions are in the link I posted :)

Comment: This is why I wrote: "_you could use ONE of redux's approach_"

Comment: @Tommy both solutions are correct, but I would say that using array's filter is (slightly) shorter and faster.